# Android IO 2013 App (iosched) Network Patterns

Tags: design-patterns, android-networking, android-syncadapter, android-volley, googleio

Is there a higher level (block diagram, etc.) or tutorial for the network access pattern used by the Google IO 2013 app ?

I know it uses `SyncAdapter` and the Volley library but I seem to get lost in the Google specific APIs such as `Plus`.

So far, I've just been using in-Activity `AsyncTasks` and would like to move to using `Volley` and investigate other patterns.

Comment: Have you seen the Google IO session where Volley is presented? https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728

Comment: I have seen that session. It doesn't mention anything about using SyncAdapters. Reto Meier does mention these in his talk but as he himself admits, the implementation is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

is AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter what you mentioned above? AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter is used for account sync.

Comment: I'm concerned with how the ListViews are populated. They seem to use a CursorAdapter but I can't figure out how the Sycning is done.